# Java - How do I use a class file?

Tags: java, class, netbeans

I'm new to Java and am wondering about how to import class files into netbeans and use it.

I understand that a class file is machine-readable byte code but I don't care what's going on under the hood. I'd just like to import it into my current project and have it recognize it so I can use the class.

Also, the class file is embedded within a JAR file. I imported the JAR file into my libraries folder/tab in the projects window but I don't know how to get my project to recognize the class. It says "cannot find symbol" whenever I try to instantiate an object.

Comment: Keep it inside the jar. Also convert to .Net while your reputation is still positive ;)

Comment: Who's to say that .NET will be any better?

Comment: @lpthnc (445) - using .Net hasn't helped your reputation much :-)

Comment: I'm at a loss for why this question was down voted.

Comment: I suppose the name of the question could be changed to something closer to what the actual question is about.

Comment: @Stephen C : lpthnc has been here for only 17 days.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to import by calling the name of source package  .  ie  `import hello.Car;`  . In your case you are trying to call  import on  JAR folder name  which leads to an error "cannot find symbol" .

Let me try to give an example for  better understandability

- Consider this simple Vehicle application which has Car class and Test Car class 
  [image]
- Convert it into jar  and  add it into  another project called  ImportVehicleJar

  [alt text http://i46.tinypic.com/qxmlxt.png](http://i46.tinypic.com/qxmlxt.png)

  - In order to instantiate the Car class   in Main.Java file  add the following as shown  in figure 
    [image]

  Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 2):

In Netbeans (version 5.5.1), you can add a jar file to a project by right clicking the project name, and choosing Properties, then Libraries (from Categories), and there is an "Add JAR/Folder" button, which can be used for adding it to the compile-time and/or run-time classpath. Adding it to the Compile-time Libraries is well enough, because it will
automatically added to the run-time through its "Classpath for Compiling Sources" entry.

Answer (score 1):

You either need to specify the full package pathname to the class. e.g

```
com.foobar.acme.Clobula myBigClobula = new com.foobar.acme.Clobula();
```

or use an import statement

```
import com.foobar.acme.Clobula
...
.
 Clobula myBigClobula = new Clobula();
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, class files aren't machine-readable / binary in the sense that compiled c files are.  Open a class file with your text editor and you will see that it is in fact a list of text instructions.  The Java Virtual Machine looks at these class files and interprets them, executing the resulting instructions.

Comment: I think Alex is meaning ".class" files, which are the files the JVM loads. These files are binary, they are not machine-code file like C files, but they are **not** text files. ".java" are text files which are compiled into bytecode to produce the ".class" file.  The classfile definition: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html

Comment: .java files are the sourcecode. .classfiles are very much readable.  Open one in a text editor.

Comment: I do not know what you mean as readable, but any classfile I opened (the last 10 years) is NOT a text file. Reading the classfile definition just confirms that: they start with magic code (0xCA 0xFE 0xBA 0xBE), followed by 3 2-byte integers for minor, major and constant-pool-count. Please send me an exampe of a (valid) classfile that is "readable". Here's what I see when opening one in a text editor: http://img254.imageshack.us/img254/6135/helloi.jpg  and here the classfile: http://simu.wikidot.com/local--files/java:java/Hello.class

Comment: From what you've posted, I can see that you have a simple program with a single System.out.println statement.  The methods / instructions are in text (hence readable).  Conversely, try looking at a compiled C file in a text editor, you do not get the same textual instructions.

Comment: just because **some** text is readable it is not a text file. You can not see (as text) if there's an `if`, other flow control commands or arithmetic in the code. Executable C also have a TEXT segment where you can read which strings are used, same true for imported library functions (as I remember).

Comment: ahh i see what you mean.  You are correct.  I thought that all of instructions were in text form in a class file, similar to what assembly would look like.  After some simple test programs, the instructions are in binary op codes (java bytecode).  Thanks for the clarification.