# How to reference classes from one NetBeans project in another Netbeans project?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have two projects, project1 and project2 for simplicity's matter. Project1 has package my.proj1 in it, that contains class myclass.

What is the correct sequence of actions to take for creating object my.proj1.myClass in one of the classes of project2?

I've tried adding project1 as reference, but for some reason that doesn't allow me to import classes from my.proj1 pakage.

Comment: Your project looks like a Maven project, the problem may be in pom.xml of the main project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click on your current project, go to Properties, then Libraries, and then you should see one of the options as "Add Project". (I haven't actually tried to see if it works.)

Comment: That's what i have done initially. To my dismay, that didn't help. Although in project view of project2 i have project1 and all its packages, NetBeans continues to claim those packages do not exist when i attempt to import them.

Comment: Maybe when you choose "Add Project", it's not the main project directory you must choose, but the base of "my.proj1" (source or compiled class directory).  I noticed that you can navigate the directories when adding a project.

Comment: See this other [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983513/java-how-do-i-use-a-class-file); you can import the jar file from "my.proj1" if nothing else works (but you need to make sure it is up to date when modifying both projects at the same time).

Comment: See also [this Oracle blog](http://blogs.oracle.com/roumen/entry/netbeans_quick_tip_16_using).  It seems that just by choosing the other project in "Add Project", its .jar will be included as a dependency.  Maybe your "my.proj1" does not yet have a .jar.  And it seems that if you recompile your main project, "my.proj1" is also recompiled if needed.

Comment: I have tried to doing exactly that. See http://tinypic.com/r/ic7fx0/7 for result.

Comment: If you had tried included the base directory of the source code, just try importing the main project instead.  And check that it has a .jar.

Comment: Have you tried also including directly "roster2-0.1.jar" (not as Add Project, but Add Jar)?  You might not have automatic updating that way however.

Comment: No, i havee not. Once i have done that, it worked. My sincere thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

You type                       -(class name)space (object name) equals new (class name);                                    now you can access components of class by object name  like  suppose u have 1 component like void input()            (object name).input:

Comment: I think the OP was having classpath issues -- the accepted answer already solved his problem.