# Working with two projects-

Tags: java

I have developed a basic desktop-app using Netbeans IDE, on the app I have a button called `Ok`. Now I have created another project, its a CRUD-app. Is there a way to make the ok-button in my 1st project to run the CRUD-app in another project- or how do I link tha ok-button to open/run the crud-app? In a different project..Project names are pro1 and CruD-test- 
Below is a sample-code for my button:

```
OK.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
//please add a link to the CRUD-app contained in project Crud-test
```

@Max: I wanna run pro1 on the IDE and run the CruD-test as jar...how do I link mu OK-button to the CruD-test?

Comment: Are you asking if you can get it to run from the IDE? Or from the compiled .jar file?

Answer (score 0):

Basically it is going to be code as :

```
OK.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
       MyCRUDApplication crudApp = new MyCRUDApplication(); //This is only an example, keep a gloabal reference as needed
       //assuming MyCRUDApplication constructor would create and show its main window.
       //Otherwise you will have to provide the relevant class that really shows the project.
}
```

For this, you should add `MyCRUDApplication` application as a referenced project in Netbeans. It is [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294202/how-to-reference-classes-from-one-netbeans-project-in-another-netbeans-project)